# Capistrano Rubber Phusion Passenger Enterprise Config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger, rubber

I am having a little trouble editing the Capistrano Rubber recipes to include the Phusion Passenger Enterprise edition instead of the open-source module.

The problem starts with the fact that the enterprise version of passenger is not available for download from any repositories. Thus, I downloaded the gem manually and have it stored in a .tar.gz file on my local machine. One thing I did notice though is that the stock Capistrano rubber recipe expects to find the gem in a repository, not a local file. And so, I assume that I need to edit the following config file, although I am not quite sure how.

Edit #1: config/rubber/rubber-passenger_nginx.yml

```
passenger_version: 3.0.11
nginx_version: 1.0.11
passenger_root: "#{`bash -l -c 'find #{ruby_path} -name passenger-#{passenger_version}'`.strip}"
passenger_ruby: "#{ruby_path}/bin/ruby"
passenger_lib: "#{passenger_root}/ext/nginx"
passenger_listen_port: 7000
passenger_listen_ssl_port: 7001
max_app_connections: 20

use_ssl_key: false
#if you use an ssl key, put your cert and key
# in
# #{Rubber.root}/config/#{rubber_env.domain} .crt and .key
#otherwise defaults to key included with linux z


roles:
  passenger_nginx:
    packages: [libcurl4-openssl-dev, libpcre3-dev]
    gems: [[passenger, "#{passenger_version}"]]
```

I also feel like I should be editing the installation routine so that I specify the location of the manually downloaded gem and point the nginx install process to it.

If anyone could offer any advice I would be very appreciative.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use Rubber in combination with a shell script that runs plain old 'gem install local-file.gem'.

The Enterprise gems and tarballs can be downloaded non-interactively. In the Customer Area, right click on a gem or tarball and copy its URL. You can then use curl or another similar tool to download that URL. You just need to pass HTTP Basic Authentication credentials too. The username is your order reference, the password is the one you received by email.